# How to copy pagesetup to a different workbook?

Tags: vba

i two workbooks . I need to copy pagesetup from wb2 to wb1 . .

`With wb1.sheets("test")
.pagesetup.footermargin = wb2.sheets("xxx").pagesetup.footermargi
End`

Comment: your question is very poor, in my humble opinion. `.FooterMargin` is just a double therefore what you posted (ignoring the missing "n") *will* work, assuming that your code above what you posted 1) correctly assigns to wb1 and has a valid sheet named "test" and 2) correctly assigns to wb2 and has a sheet named "xxx" 3) `End` meant to be `End With`. You therefore, as far as my experience can tell, have not put the full question in and left out a lot of very relevant code that would help to explain why such a simple instruction to Excel VBA is not working as expected. Sorry if this sounds harsh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub savefooter()
Dim twb as workbook
Dim wb2 as workbook
Dim a as variant
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Set twb = ThisWorkbook
a = twb.Sheets("Sheet1").PageSetup.FooterMargin
Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open("C:\b.xlsx") ' set path to where your second wb is
wb2.Sheets("Sheet1").PageSetup.FooterMargin = a
wb2.Save
wb2.Close
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```